# selenium alternative for python? Fastest way to access web elements

Tags: python, brute-force

I am trying to create a brute forcer. In my current version, I am just using selenium and finding web elements this way. This seems slow, maybe because it loads the whole website. (just a locally hosted panel). Anyone know a better way to do this, maybe without making an automated browser? For anyone wondering, i'm trying to find 2 elements, and there is no api etc, so I assume I can't do this by the requests lib in python.

Comment: As long as the content you are interested in is contained in web elements that are not loaded dynamically, then `BeautifulSoup` is a great resource for this. Simply use the `requests` library to request the source HTML and then pass it to `BeautifulSoup` to search for the elements you are interested in.

Comment: In addition to what rahlf23 mentioned (which is great for static content combined with urllib) you can also look into PyQt4/5.  PyQt was a bit more cumbersome than selenium, but significantly faster and does some things much better.  You can find tutorials for a basic scraping script using it with a quick google search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BeautifulSoup` is the de-facto standard library for parsing web pages in Python. It's great for sever-rendered or static content. It breaks down on sites that prevent web scraping, that dynamically update with client-side rendering, or that require cookies or authentication.

So what do you use when `BeautifulSoup` doesn't cut it?

Check out [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/). It's Javascript-native, but it has [backend adapters](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/794) in work for Python, Node, Ruby, php, and .NET.

Even without the adapters, Cypress is a powerful tool for e2e testing and browser automation that eliminates all the pain that comes with Selenium. If the information you're trying to scrape requires authentication, cookies, interaction, or is hampered by anti-bot code, give it a shot.

If you already know about inspecting requests using your browser's dev tools you can stop reading here. Else...

---

And finally, all this is assuming you've already inspected the network tab in your browser's dev tools to verify the data you're looking for isn't coming across XHR in an easily parseable format. If you haven't looked there yet, here are some Chrome instructions:

Right click the page of interest -> Inspect -> Network -> Refresh page -> click xhr filter

Then:

Browse the response tab of each api call to see if the data of interest is hiding in plain sight. If the data you want is there, check the request tab to see whether your browser had to look at the request parameters you had to send to get it. If it's a simple GET request, chances are you can just copy that url straight into your browser and it'll be the data you want. If it's a POST, you can experiment with a tool like Servistate or Postman to see what sticks. I'd copy the request as it was in the browser identically, then pull stuff out or swap stuff in the POST body and in the other params to see how it works and what I can get away with. If it doesn't require you to have a cookie, you can get away with `urllib` in Python. If it does, just use Cypress, it'll save you time.

Comment: +1 for explaining how to look for XHR. I've seen some others mentioning it in other posts but without explaining how to actually use devtools to find it.

Comment: Thank you for the help, especially explaining xhr, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use headless chrome to get the elements. This would speed up the process of getting the elements.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome

Other option is using scrapy for crawling a webpage to get the information you want for processing information.

Comment: selenium is the issue, not the broswer. running chrome in headless more wont make it noticeably more efficient. as well, scrapy is a web crawling framework and way too much for what OP needs, and would end up actually being worse. he just needs a better html parser.

Comment: The problem as mentioned is loading of the page. Making it headless would speed  up the process. But yes you are right, maybe sending a HTTP request to the browser and parsing the html response would resolve the error unless there are any ajax calls which populate the elements.

Comment: a headless browser still renders the content, though. it just doesn't have a graphical interface for the user. the rendering engine for chrome versus headless chrome is the same. to elaborate on the second part of what you said, so long as there is no javascript/ajax/jquery/etc., he can simply use `requests` or `urllib`, or even `mechanize` to get the html response from the page and use an html parser such as `beautifulsoup` to parse it, which will be incredibly fast.